# CodeIgniter is_unique Error Message in Language File

Tags: php, codeigniter

When using CodeIgniter I like to set my error messages in `application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php` which works fine for every error message but does not seem to work for the `is_unique` message as it gives me the standard message of "The email field must contain a unique value."

My code:

`$lang['is_unique'] = "The %s entered is already in use.";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `form_validation_lang.php` in so like below

- application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php

**Go to system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php find.**

```
$lang['form_validation_is_unique'] = 'The {field} field must contain a unique value.';
```

**Copy Key Above Then Add Into application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php**

```
$lang['form_validation_is_unique'] = 'The {field} entered is already in use.';
```

Next

**On Controller Form Validation Add**

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'english');
```

**Like**

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'english');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|is_unique[users.username]');
```

**Note:** If you use the form_validation is_unique in other controllers and want to use that message you will need to load this `$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'english');` On to that controller as well unless you choose to autoload it.

Comment: is there no way to set it in the application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php? Also as a note to anyone else, never change any file in the /system/ folder as it will cause problems when you attempt to update.

Comment: I am not sure, also I would not have the form_validation_lang.php named like that because there is one in system lang called that. I just use the set_message, like above to change message.

Comment: It is named like that to overwrite the original, CI3 docs: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Comment: I updated my answer not tested though you may need to autoload that lang file.

Comment: The key was the variable naming. $lang['is_unique'] needed to be changed to $lang['form_validation_is_unique'], based on you answer above.

Comment: I got it working the way on my answer now works fine that way